# So the first if statement never triggers because it does not seem to read the negative number entered in the text box

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double temp = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    if (temp < 0)
    {
        label2.Text = "Freezing.";
    }
    if (temp > 40)
    {
        label2.Text = "Hot.";
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "Moderate.";
    }
}
```

Comment: put a break point in the `double temp = ....` and see what you get ... we can go on from there

Comment: Try it in an else if....

Comment: What happens if you add a `textBox1.Text = "-32";` before the first line?

Comment: Your first 'if' does trigger. However, the else clause of the second 'if' will overwrite it with "Moderate".  Add an else before the second if.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever converting user input, or any form of type String in to an object, I always like to use TryParse(...) as it provides you with better control if something isn't right.

```
double temp = 0.0d;
var converted = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp);
if (!converted) throw new Exception("Please enter a positive or negative temperature.");
if (temp < 0.0d)
{
    // Freezing
}
else if (temp >= 0.0d && temp < 40.0d)
{
    // Moderate
}
else if (temp >= 40.0d)
{
    // Hot
}
```

Comment: +1, Nice ordering of ranges, note that `temp >= 0.0d` is not really needed, but makes it more readable.

Comment: It is a common practice that I follow for basically that; readability. I'm unaware if it poses any performance issues, although I haven't encountered any as of yet.
Thanks for the comment, @AlexeiLevenkov.

Answer (score 1):

The key is finding out what the value is being read in to `temp`. If its bringing in a negative number then I would recommend the code change below. What its really doing is if the 1st isnt true, then it checks the second, and finally it uses the third if neither are true.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double temp = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    if (temp < 0)
    {
        label2.Text = "Freezing.";
    }
    else if (temp > 40)
    {
        label2.Text = "Hot.";
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "Moderate.";
    }
}
```